# Unable to launch Android emulator from Eclipse/Linux

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, opensuse

I'm using Eclipse Juno (build 20120920-0800) on openSUSE 12.2 to code Android applications.

I have installed the SDK by uncompressing it into my home directory (if I install the SDK via YaST package I can't download stuff unless I'm root). I installed ADT from Eclipse Marketplace, configured the path of the SDK and configured a couple of emulator configurations.

I can run and debug fine on my phone, and I guess the same applies to my tablet even if I haven't tried yet.

The real problem is that I **can't run the emulator**. Clicking on the `bacarozzo` debug icon prompts me to run the application on the device but doesn't show me available emulators.
[image: Debug screen]

If I open the device manager I'm shown with the virtual devices I created but I can't just start any. The progress bar reaches the end, I see no emulator screen and if I try to delete the emulator I'm warned that the instance is running... (OK in the screenshot there is only one, I already managed to delete the other)
[image: ADT Device Manager]

I urge to test some GUI features in an outdated version of Android. I have done all the field tests of the business logic code in my program on a JB device and I know for sure **that** code works on any device.

Now I only need to be backward-compatible with preferences and layouts.

How can I start the emulator in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by luck I managed to run the emulator from console

```
djechelon@RAYNOR:~/android-sdk-linux/tools> ./emulator-arm -avd Emulator_cell
```

It came to life and Eclipse debug is detecting it as active device